# Firebase iOS setup - nil senderID

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

When trying to setup Firebase for iOS, I get this error in the console:

```
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Firebase messaging not setup correctly, nil senderID.
```

Looks like Firebase doesn't detect well my `GoogleService-Info.plist`, I tried putting it a few locations (root included) but it didn't work. Any idea/pointer on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple, I just forgot to put `[FIRApp configure];` in `AppDelegate.m`

EDIT: And if your get this error, it means you forgot to add `GoogleService-Info.plist` to all the targets (as described by the other answer):

```
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file `GoogleService-Info.plist` is included with all the targets for which your app builds code that uses Firebase.
[image]

Comment: thanks but the problem was just that I forgot to call "configure"...but your answer can maybe else other people.